# handle datatype issue while reading excel file to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm having an excel(.xlsx) file with following columns

```
Location    Month       Desc            Position    Budget
EUR         1/1/2020    In Europe       Right       34%
AUS         1/1/2020    In Australia    Left        >22%
```

While reading this file in pandas df, Im facing issue in Budget col. Getting the below error:

```
field Budget: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'>
Could not convert '>22%' with type str: tried to convert to double
```

Im trying with this code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").getOrCreate()

pdf = pandas.read_excel(parent_path+'file1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

fileSchema = StructType([
  StructField("Location", StringType()),
  StructField("Month", DateType()),
  StructField("Desc", StringType()),
  StructField("Position", StringType()),
  StructField("Budget", StringType())])

pdf.fillna('')
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)

df.show()
```

I need to read multiple excel files. How to handle the datatype issue here? Any sugestions

Comment: How do you want to convert `>22%` to a double? Will there be values like `<20%`?

Comment: Yes there will be values like <20%, >20%. I want the exact values present in that column in the dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you could deal with that using a custom `converter`:

```
def bcvt(x):
    return float(x.replace('>','').replace('%',''))/100

dfd = pd.read_csv(r'd:\jchtempnew\t1.csv', converters={'Budget': bcvt})

dfd 

  Location     Month          Desc Position  Budget
0      EUR  1/1/2020     In Europe    Right    0.34
1      AUS  1/1/2020  In Australia     Left    0.22
```

(Updated per `@user128029` recommendation)

Comment: nitpick: stylistically that should just be a normal function and not a lambda (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).